# ifstream to find existing files c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-xp

I am attempting to save some real-time graph data from a block of code I have written for OpenGL that's currently communicating with an Arduino. So far I have had plenty of problems porting from Win10 VS15 to WinXP VS10, but alas those are the circumstances I am in.

I want my program to attempt to open an existing file and check if it is open.

If the file is open I want to modify the path (appending incrementing numbers) and retesting until the file does not open.

If/when the file does not open I then use that path to output my data to a new file.

```
int graph::save(const char *_path, int _format){
int i;
char *path;
double *_data;

char ext[9];

int _state = !state; //state is a class variable

if (_format == 0){
    sprintf(ext, "plot");
}
else if (_format == 1){
    sprintf(ext, "plotx");
}
else {
    printf("Invalid save format\n");
    return(1);
}

_data = new double[data.length];

//swap data stream buffer with static buffer if initially active
if (_state){pause();}

//copy data to new buffer to allow OpenGL loop access to data buffer
for (register int i = 0; i <= data.length; i++){
    _data[i] = data.data[i];
}

if (_state){pause();} //return to initial state if initially active

path = new char[strlen(_path) + 6 + 7]; //resize for extension

sprintf(path, "%s.%s", _path, ext); //append file extension

//open file
std::ifstream file((const char *)path, std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);

i = 1;
while(file.is_open()){ //while file is open(able)
    file.close(); //close opened file
    sprintf(path, "%s[%i].%s", _path, i, ext); //append incrementing number
    //open new file
    std::ifstream file((const char *)path, std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);
    i++;
}

file.close(); //close file

//open ofstream with un-openable file path
//store data etc etc (this all works)
```

Compiles, runs, press 's' to save, 'l' to load. This all works fine.

Save first time:

```
file.plot
```

Save second time:

```
file.plot
file[1].plot
```

Save x times:

```
file.plot
file[1].plot
```

While debugging it shows that file[1].plot is being opened even when it already exists, so my loop is exiting.

Note:
I do not care for portability right now as working code comes first, however I do appreciate any formatting advice as I try to keep my code as understandable as possible. I have never used the _variable convention before so, critique away.

Comment: `std::ifstream file((const char *)path, std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);`  This is a local variable inside that loop.  That variable has nothing to do with the `file` variables you've defined before or after the loop.  And to be honest, that is a whole lot of code that should be doing something straightforward (if your description is correct).  Also, why not use `std::string` and/or `std::vector` instead of `new[ ]`?

Comment: Until recently I have only coded in C, not C++. I am still slowly learning the differences as there's no urgent need to rewrite code I have already written in C that still compiles/works just fine under C++. I have only been formally educated in C so I've found the transition a little difficult. So, I've just gone and used new[] in place of malloc/realloc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `file` in your loop condition, and that you close, does not refer to the variable declared inside the loop.
Since you close the "outside" file on the first iteration, you will only iterate once.

To reuse the same variable, use `file.open(path, std::ios::binary | std::ios::in)`.
(There is no point in casting non-const to const – don't cast unless you know that it's both necessary and correct.)

And `i <= data.length` will lead to out-of-bounds array accesses, which is undefined.

Comment: So I should treat ifstream like an identifier?

I have... oh boy, I missed the i <= data.length in this loop, I checked and my other loops all use  i < data.length. Thank you! I would have left it and never noticed otherwise.

Comment: @Jarred An identifier is a name – "ifstream" is an identifier, and so are "file" and "sprintf". The problem is that you have two completely different variables with the same name.

Comment: I've spent a few years studying and using C, but I'm still very new to C++. I believe I meant 'data type' not identifier... that's a little embarrassing. Thereby being, should I treat ifstream like a data type? I was unaware I was initiating a variable, I was under the impression I was doing... now that it has been pointed out to me I don't know what I was doing!

Comment: @Jarred Not only should you treat it as a data type, it is a data type. A struct is a type in C, too. (My guess is that you believed that you were "reinitialising" the same object.)

Comment: I thought I was using a function or something like that. I've changed my use of ifstream/ofstream and it's working now. Thank you.